# Concurrency and NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, concurrency, nsurlconnection

Recently I've been researching and working with `NSURLConnection` and concurrency.
There seem to be several different approaches, and the ones I've tried (dispatch queues and operation queues) all seemed to work properly, eventually.

One problem I encountered with concurrency and `NSURLConnection`, is the delegate methods not being called. After some research I found out the `NSURLConnection` needs to either be scheduled in the main runloop, or the `NSOperation` should be running on the main thread. In the first case I'm invoking `NSURLConnection` like this:

```
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
[connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[connection start];
```

And in the latter case like this:

```
- (void)start
{
    if (![NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(start) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;
    }
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

The delegate methods handle everything else, and both seem to work properly.
In the case when I was using a dispatch queue, I did the same as with the first case (schedule the `NSURLConnection` in the main runloop).

My question is, what's the difference between these two approaches? Or are they actually the same, but just a different way of implementing them?

The second question is, why is this necessary? I'm also using an `NSXMLParser` inside an `NSOperation`, and this doesn't seem to require a main runloop or main thread, it just works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I figured it out myself. Since both `NSURLConnection` and `NSXMLParser` are asynchronous, they require a run loop for the delegate messages when they're running in the background.
As far as I know now, the main thread automatically keeps the run loop running; the main run loop. So both solutions for `NSURLConnection` I posted will make sure the main run loop is used for the asynchronous part, either by telling the connection to use the main run loop for the delegate messages, or by moving the entire operation onto the main thread, which will automatically schedule the connection on the main thread as well.

What I've come up with now, is to keep a run loop running on my custom `NSOperation` classes, so I no longer have to perform any scheduling or thread checking. I've implemented the following at the end of the `(void)start` method:

```
// Keep running the run loop until all asynchronous operations are completed
while (![self isFinished]) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
```

Comment: You're welcome :) Btw, currently I would recommend using [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com) instead, I think it's a lot easier to use than `NSURLConnection` etc.